# NS_ENUM to Swift 3 not working as expected

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm using Swift 3 and xcode 8. I'm very new to objective-C and fairly new to swift, so maybe this is an idiot question. But here goes!

I'm bridging from objective-C to swift 3. Here's a code snippet of the objective-C:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MaplyMapType) {
    MaplyMapType3D,
    MaplyMapTypeFlat,
};

@interface MaplyViewController : MaplyBaseViewController

/// @brief Initialize as a flat or 3D map.
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithMapType:(MaplyMapType)mapType;
```

In my Swift 3 source file I instantiate a MaplyViewController. The following is the WORKING code (it compiles and runs, and no xcode errors).

```
theViewC = MaplyViewController(mapType: .typeFlat)
```

Why does this work? From references https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html and other references I think the correct code should be:

```
theViewC = MaplyViewController(mapType: .flat)
```

But that won't compile.

**MORE INFO FROM ONE DAY LATER:** Amin Negm-Awad in his comment below has almost explained this. The simple bridging rules cannot be used to produce identifiers .flat and .3D because identifier .3D is not allowed.  The [language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID412) says "Identifiers begin with an uppercase or lowercase letter A through Z, an underscore (_), a noncombining alphanumeric Unicode character in the Basic Multilingual Plane, or a character outside the Basic Multilingual Plane that isn’t in a Private Use Area. After the first character, digits and combining Unicode characters are also allowed."

So the bridging cannot result in enum identifiers .flat and .3d. I could not find any reference to explain the rules bridging uses to come up with the alternative identifies, namely .typeFlat and .type3D in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely it is, because the other identifier (`MaplyMapType3D`) would be `3D`instead of `type3D`, but identifiers must not start with a digit. So one has to keep `type`.